# CSS multi-level drop-down menu doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build multi-level CSS dropdown. I found a simple demo code and tried to edit but when I customized the third level of dropdown it became broken. I'm hoping to use `<div>` instead of `<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>` as I'd like to put multiple elements like `<ul>`, `<li>` and `<p>`. Below is the final image of the dropdown. If I hover Sub Menu 2 or Sub Menu 3, third level dropdown will appear next to each each `<li>` tag.
[image]

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
}
/* first level */
nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #111;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #009a9c;
    color: #fff;
}
/* second level */
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: #43c6db;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
/* hover effect for second level */
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    height: 40px;
    background: #009a9c;
    color: #fff;
}
nav > ul > li:hover li:hover > a {
    background: #009a9c;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul >li {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 40px;
}
/* thir level */
nav ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

nav ul li:last-child ul li ul {
    left: 100%;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    background: #43c6db;
}
nav ul li ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
/* hover effect for third level */
nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 200;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul >li:hover > a {
    background: #009a9c;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Second level arrow direction */
nav > ul > li > ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: -20px;
    right: 16px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #111;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul:before {
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
/* Third level arrow direction */
nav ul li ul li ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 16px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover ul:before {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:last-child ul li ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 16px;
    left: 200%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:last-child ul li:hover ul:before {
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">menu 3-1</a>
            <!-- original code I found -->
                    <!--<ul>
                        <li><a href="#">menu 3-1-1</a></li>
                    </ul>-->
            <!-- Want to customize like this -->
                    <div>
                        <p>Text</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Some menu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Some menu</a></li>
                            </ul>           
                    </div>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your styles get overridden, for example:

```
/* first level */
nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

This style will affect all of your li elements, not just the first-level list items. You can use classes like `class='first-level'` or even the `>` operator for more specific elements selectors, like in the snippet below:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
}
/* first level */
nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #111;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #009a9c;
    color: #fff;
}
/* second level */
nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background: #43c6db;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
/* hover effect for second level */
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    height: 40px;
    background: #009a9c;
    color: #fff;
}
nav > ul > li:hover li:hover > a {
    background: #009a9c;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul >li {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 40px;
}
/* thir level */
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

nav > ul > li:last-child > ul> li> ul {
    left: 100%;
}

nav >ul >li >ul >li >ul >li {
    width: 100%;
    background: #43c6db;
}
nav >ul >li> ul> li> ul >li> a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
/* hover effect for third level */
nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 200;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul >li:hover > a {
    background: #009a9c;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Second level arrow direction */
nav > ul > li > ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: -20px;
    right: 16px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #111;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul:before {
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
/* Third level arrow direction */
nav ul li ul li ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 16px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover ul:before {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:last-child ul li ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 16px;
    left: 200%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:last-child ul li:hover ul:before {
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">menu 3-1</a>
            <!-- original code I found -->
                    <!--<ul>
                        <li><a href="#">menu 3-1-1</a></li>
                    </ul>-->
            <!-- Want to customize like this -->
                    <div>
                        <div>Text</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Some menu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Some menu</a></li>
                            </ul>           
                    </div>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</nav>
```